# How to implement bluetooth for all device in react native

Tags: android, react-native, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I want to scan and connect devices using Bluetooth in React-Native. I tried [react-native-ble-manager](https://github.com/innoveit/react-native-ble-manager) and [react-native-ble-plx](https://github.com/Polidea/react-native-ble-plx) plugins.

But I have a problem these plugins connected to special devices that have peripheral mode enabled. [Look this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47678609/using-ble-between-devices-with-react-native).

**Question:**

How can I implement Bluetooth for all (at least all smartphones) devices in REACT-NATIVE?

Comment: did you figure it out ?

Comment: @AmitJS94 yes I did it with `react-native-bluetooth-serial` by `@rusel1989` [github repo](https://github.com/rusel1989/react-native-bluetooth-serial)

Comment: @MasoudTavakkoli do you know if it works for connecting 2 phones and than sharing data between them?

Comment: @M.Wojcik Unfortunately No!