# How to scan non-BLE (a.k.a. standard) Bluetooth devices in React Native?

Tags: bluetooth, react-native, android-bluetooth

I have used react-native-ble-manager but I couldn't find my device because it is not BLE!

How can I scan and search for standard Bluetooth devices in React Native?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please add more details to your question, including any code you have tried so far?

Comment: thank you! I have used this package: react-native-ble-manager and it scans all bluetooth devices except standard one! it just scan BLE devices, my device is not BLE so my application can not find that! I want a package for finding any kind of bluetooth devices.

Comment: Related question: [How to implement bluetooth for all device in react native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48790170/how-to-implement-bluetooth-for-all-device-in-react-native?rq=1) recommending the library [react-native-bluetooth-serial](https://github.com/rusel1989/react-native-bluetooth-serial).